# Getting error 403 forbidden after enabling readonly in tomcat Server on HTTP PUT method

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, web.xml, readonly, put

when i try to do a **PUT** method through **postman** i get the 403 error.

I'm currently using **Tomcat 7** and from what I understand by adding **readonly** to the web.xml servlet part will stop the 403 error and allow the PUT method to work. However, when I did this and went back on postman and tired to do a PUT I was still getting the **403 Forbidden error**.

Is there any other way to resolve this problem and allow the PUT method to work?

This is the part I was enabling the readonly on the **web.xml** in my Tomcat server:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>readonly</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

Comment: The configuration you're referencing is for the DefaultServlet.  This is what serves up static files in Tomcat, hence the default of "true" for the "readonly" parameter.  Are you really trying to PUT something to the default servlet or are you trying to PUT something to an application you have running in Tomcat (i.e. to a custom servlet)?

Comment: I'm trying to PUT something to an application I have running in Tomcat

Comment: The the above configuration is not relevant then.  Tomcat is not going to prevent a PUT request from going to your application, especially not by returning a 403.  Look at your application and see why it's not working properly.  Perhaps you've got some type of security (Servlet / web.xml, Spring Security, etc..) configured and it's not allowing a PUT request through.

Comment: Hey, I checked my application and figured it out thanks :)

Comment: @user3661128, hi can you share your solution, i met same issue when try to enable delete/put in my restful services